Something faster than RandomReal and RandomInteger?
I am dealing with the code sequentially producing random numbers and using them further for some operations.
The code snippet looks like
code = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{sum = 0., len = Length[data], n1, n2, val = 0.},
   Do[
    n1 = RandomInteger[{1, len}];
    n2 = RandomInteger[{1, len}];
    val = 
     Compile`GetElement[data, n1, 1]/Compile`GetElement[data, n2, 2];
    If[val < Random[], sum += val];
    , {i, 1, n, 1}];
   sum], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

Also, there is its analog that just replaces random generators with some other operations:
code1 = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{sum = 0., len = Length[data], n1, n2, val = 0.},
   Do[
    n1 = Mod[i, len];
    n2 = Mod[i + 4, len];
    val = 
     Compile`GetElement[data, n1, 1]/Compile`GetElement[data, n2, 2];
    If[val < 0.5, sum += val];
    , {i, 1, n, 1}];
   sum], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

Of course, the operation
    val = 
     Compile`GetElement[data, n1, 1]/Compile`GetElement[data, n2, 2];
    If[val < 0.5, sum += val];

is just a very simplified version of what I am doing. But the point is that random number generation is the bottleneck of my code:
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4000, 2}];
code[data, 10^7] // AbsoluteTiming
code1[data, 10^7] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.300602,827676.}
{0.111158,650076.}

My question is whether it is possible to generate random numbers faster within Mathematica. I was thinking of writing a C++ code and importing it using LibraryLink, but it looks like it is not possible to use a library made in C++ inside Compile. So, if I try to follow this method, I would need to write the entire loop (with all the complex operations) in C++.
Is there any workaround?

SeedRandom accepts an option Method where you can choose a different PRNG. Have you tried with that? Obviously, there is always some trade-off between the quality and speed.

RandomInteger[{1, 4000}, {10^7, 2}] is faster than 2*10^7 iterations of individual RandomInteger[] calls.

@Domen : not yet, will do. But I have checked on a slower machine that the C++ code may perform a similar task already 3 times faster.

@MichaelE2 : so you propose to generate them in advance and then access the table? It may work, but in my actual code there are some operations that (rarely) modify the size of data inside the loop, which makes this option not so attractive.

@Domen : the default method is the fastest one.

Since n >> len, it might be more efficient to tally up the unique indices, calculate the val for each index, and then find the number of each value of val that pass by using BinomialDistribution like this. The sampling of the BinomialDistribution I believe is the bottleneck here, but this looks to be about twice as fast.

Nevermind, I didn't even see you have a method code1 that is faster than this already. I really need to start reading closer.

Yes, generate the random indices once for all. A varying len will complicate things.

I added a faster version of code1 here as well. Note that in your code1 CompileGetElement[data, n1, 1]is going to behave unexpectedly whenn1orn2` are equal to 0.

As pointed out before, no need to iterate simple operations like RandomInteger etc, via loops like Do, see my answer below.

No need to generate random numbers with every Do loop iteration.
code2=Compile[{{data,_Real,2},{n,_Integer},{n1s,_Integer,1},{n2s,_Integer,1},{randoms,_Real,1}},Module[{sum=0.,len=Length[data],n1,n2,val=0.},
Do[
n1=n1s[[i]];
n2=n2s[[i]];
val=Compile`GetElement[data,n1,1]/Compile`GetElement[data,n2,2];
If[val<randoms[[i]],sum+=val];,{i,1,n,1}
];
sum
],CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed"];

RepeatedTiming[
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4000, 2}];
code[data, 10^7];
]

RepeatedTiming[
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4000, 2}];
code1[data, 10^7];
]

RepeatedTiming[
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4000, 2}];
n1s=RandomInteger[Length@data-1,10^7]+1;
n2s=RandomInteger[Length@data-1,10^7]+1;
randoms=RandomReal[1,10^7];
code2[data,10^7,n1s,n2s,randoms];
]


{0.662901, Null}


{0.398102, Null}


{0.357896, Null}

UPD
This is yet a bit faster:
RepeatedTiming[data=RandomReal[1,{4000,2}];
n1s=RandomInteger[{1,Length@data},10^7];
n2s=RandomInteger[{1,Length@data},10^7];
randoms=RandomReal[1,10^7];
code2[data,10^7,n1s,n2s,randoms];]


{0.263524, Null}

